# What does 'press one's concern' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms-in-context

Example.

How has she most effectively pressed her concerns about the rules of the institution?

Answer (score 1):

She thinks that there are problems with the rules -- these are her concerns.

She has done things to try hard to persuade people to fix those problems -- this is pressing them.